# Multinomial Distribution Sufficient Statistic

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I've read that for distributions that belong to the exponential family, there is a specific solution for finding their sufficient statistic.

First, I show that the multinomial belongs to the exponential family.

$p(x|\pi)=\frac{N!}{x_{1}!....x_{k}!}\pi_{1}^{x_{1}}\pi_{2}^{x_{2}}...\pi_{k}^{x_{k}}=A(x)e^{\sum_{k=1}^{K}x_{k}log(\pi_{k})},$

where $A(x)=\frac{N!}{x_{1}!....x_{k}!}$, hence it belongs to the exponential family.

However, I have to use further calculations in order to brint the form of $p(x|\pi)$ as

$p(x|\pi)=A(x)e^{C(\pi)T(x)+B(\pi)},$

where $C(\pi)$ and $B(\pi)$ are functions of $\pi_{1},\pi_{2},...,\pi_{k}$ and $T(x)$ corresdpons to the sufficient statistic of the Multinomial.

Thus, I would like some help on how to make that further calculation, or if there is a different way that the sufficient statistic of a Multinomial can be calculated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We suppose that $x_i$ is a number of trials in which outcome number $i$ appeared, $1 \le i \le $.  Hence $x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_N = n$ where $n$ is the size of the sample $X$.

Statistic $T(X)$ is sufficient iff $p(X| \pi) = h(X) g_{\pi}(T(X))$. Thus $(x_1, \ldots, x_N)$ is sufficient. Moreover, as $x_N = n - x_1 - \ldots - x_{N-1}$ then

$$T = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{N-1})$$
is sufficient statistics.

Comment: That's what I was also expecting.